# Change breadcrumb colors bootstrap-vue

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I'd like to use bootstrap-vue breadcrumbs, but they seem to have built in background and text colors.   I've tried many combinations of classes and styles in the breadcrumb and breadcrumb-item tags, but with no effect.  The following always produces blue or grey text on a light grey background.

```
  <b-breadcrumb style="nothing works" :items="crumbs">
    <b-breadcrumb-item class="nothing works" v-for="(item, i) in crumbs" :key="i" :to="item.to">{{item.text}}</b-breadcrumb-item>
  </b-breadcrumb>
```

I don't know css too well, but I suspect there's a selector that knows how to reach inside of the generated html to fix style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style>
  .breadcrumb-item a {
    color: red
  }
</style>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  /* scoped/module (s)css */
</style>
```

... ***will*** work, because breadcrumb colors are applied by `a` selector in Bootstrap 4.

Note it can't be scoped. For some reason `::v-deep` no longer works. If you only want it in this component, place a class on the top element and prefix your selectors with that class
(i.e: `.my-component .breadcrumb-item a {...}`)

And no, there's nothing you can apply at markup level, as `<b-breadcrumb>` is just a placeholder which gets replaced by actual bootstrap markup at runtime. And so is `<b-breadcrumb-item>`.

[Examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/breadcrumb/#overview) of actual bootstrap breadcrumb markup. By default, in BootstrapVue they are:

```
ol.breadcrumb > li.breadcrumb-item > a
```

..., with the exception of the active (last) one, which is a

```
ol.breadcrumb > li.breadcrumb-item.active > span
```

Full list of available [breadcrumb item properties](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/breadcrumb/#comp-ref-b-breadcrumb-item-props) in BootstrapVue.

Comment: Yes.  Thanks.  And I did read through the breadcrumb item props.  No hint there that would have led me to your answer.  It seems strange to me, that to know this, I need to know that the breadcrumb wraps an anchor tag.  I guess I could find that by inspecting the dom, but it seems like the docs are lacking here.

Comment: Also, FYI, I had to add `  .breadcrumb { background-color:transparent; }` to the style section to make the background not grey.  (Seems odd that a general purpose object like this would commit to a fixed color).

Comment: @danh, I don't find it strange at all. The purpose of BootstrapVue is to provide everything Bootstrap 4 has to offer through Vue components, without jQuery. It doesn't eliminate your need to learn Bootstrap 4 and I don't think they'll ever document Bootstrap markup. You simply need to use Bootstrap's docs for that.

Comment: Deep selectors should work `.breadcrumb /deep/ .breadcrumb-item > a { /* rules here */ }` when using scoped styles.  Not all CSS/SCSS preprocessors like `::v-deep` or `>>>` as mentioned in the vue loader docs https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

Comment: @Troy, I have tried both `>>>` and `/deep/` before answering and for some reason none worked. There's a small chance it had to do with the particular project I tested it in, but I don't think so. Anyway, I hope they don't remove `>>>` / `::v-deep` / `/deep/` support from Vue.

Comment: Also, in this particular case, is there any difference between `.breadcrumb >>> .breadcrumb-item a` and `>>> .breadcrumb .breadcrumb-item a`? Because I only tested prefixing the entire rule with `>>>` but I believe that should have worked. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: If `<b-breadcrumb>` is a direct child in your component, it will get Vue's scoped style data attribute on the root element (the element with class `.breadcrumb`), so you will need to place the deep selector after `.breadcrumb` not before it.

Comment: @Troy, in my (quite recent) project, it doesn't. It only works if I remove `lang="scss"`. I tried with both `node-sass` and `dart-sass` compilers and it just doesn't. I also tried on a completely new project (with `vue create test`). Using `@vue/cli 4.2.3`. On `codesandbox.io`, which uses an older version of cli it still works. I'm giving up for now.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the !important tag at the end of your style: https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/

another thing is that you could try and style the element directly

```
b-breadcrumb-item {
  color: red;
}
```

Also this could be because you are not loading your styles when building the app:

What you would need is to implement a CSS loader:

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/extract-css.html

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/css-modules.html

Ive posted some links here for further reading

Comment: Thanks, but no effect.

Comment: your style isn't "nothing works" though is it? because you would ahve to style ```.nothing``` to see anything

Comment: Also, are you hard refreshing your page after running youir ```build``` because VueJs can cache the page.

Comment: Thanks @SweetChillyPhilly.  No, "nothing works" wasn't the style :-), just expressing frustration.  And, yes, I did often test with a rebuild.